# How to properly send redirect to URL on express app

Tags: node.js, http, express, redirect, cors

I'm trying for days now to send a valid redirect request in my App.
What should happen:
If I try to perform an action that requires me to be logged in, my express app should redirect to the login URL.

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.session.user == null){
        res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/#/login');
    }
    else
        next();
});
```

My CORS implementation:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin:  process.env.ctxCliente,
  credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4200/#/login. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
>   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

On my Angular App I'm sending {withCredentials: true} with all requests, because I need to use a cookie to verify the user session id

Comment: If all of this happens within your app, then why is this a cross-domain request in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe My express app is on port 3000 and my Angular app is on port 4200

Comment: Well the error message tells you what is basically wrong - you need to send a more specific `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response to the preflight request in such a case, than just `*`.

Comment: In my corsOptions the origin is specified. process.env.ctxCliente is 'http://localhost:4200'

Comment: Try using `origin: true` in `corsOptions`

Comment: @sideshowbarker Just did, same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I solved the problem:
Angular should intercept https request and check for redirects.
Here is how an interceptor can be implemented:
https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses